# Find Extremum of Functional with No Initial Conditions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I have the following functional

$ J(x)=\int\limits_{a}^{b}[{y(x)^2 + \dot{y}(x)^2 + 2 y(x) e^x}] dx $

and I want to find the extremum of it.

So I compute the Euler-Lagrange Equation and I get the result:

$ y^*(x) = c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}-{e^x\over 4}+{xe^x\over 2} $

What can be done from here to find the $c_1$ and $c_2$ since I don't have any initial conditions ? Or at least the form that they should have ?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Up to constant factors we may write OP's functional as
   $$ S[y]~:=~\int_a^b \!dx ~L , \qquad L ~:=~ \frac{1}{2}\dot{y}^2 + \frac{1}{2}( y+e^x)^2 ~\geq~0 .\tag{1}$$
2. [EL equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) is
   $$ \ddot{y}-y~=~e^x.\tag{2}$$
3. OP has already found the complete solution
   $$ y^{\ast}(x)~=~\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{3}{4}+c_+\right)e^x + c_-e^{-x},\tag{3}$$
   so that
   $$\begin{align} \dot{y}^{\ast}(x)&~=~\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+c_+\right)e^x - c_-e^{-x}, \cr 
   y^{\ast}(x)+e^x&~=~\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+c_+\right)e^x + c_-e^{-x}.\end{align}\tag{4}$$
4. Therefore the Lagrangian becomes on-shell$^1$ equal to 
   $$\begin{align}L^{\ast}(x)&~=~L^{\ast}_+(x)+L^{\ast}_-(x), \cr 
   L^{\ast}_+(x)&~:=~ \left(\frac{x}{2}+c_+\right)^2e^{2x}~\geq~0, \cr
   L^{\ast}_-(x)&~:=~\left(\frac{1}{4}e^x+c_-e^{-x}\right)^2~\geq~0 ,\end{align}\tag{5}$$
   while the functional on-shell is
   $$S[y^{\ast}]~=~S_+(c_+)+S_-(c_-), \qquad S_{\pm}(c_{\pm})~:=~\int_a^b \!dx ~L^{\ast}_{\pm}(x).\tag{6}$$
5. Clearly it now just remains to minimize $S_{\pm}(c_{\pm})$ independently,
   which is a straightforward exercise.

--

$^1$ The word *on-shell* means that the EL eq. is satisfied.

Comment: "On shell" means that the argument of the Lagrangian solves the EL equations?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.